Lumped (diagonal) vs. consistent (non-diagonal, symmetric) mass matrix in Nastran
I've been tinkering with DMAP to explore the procedure followed by Nastran when solving a complex modes analysis.
I've reached a passage I cannot understand: at some point Nastran formulated what it calls the elemental mass matrix, which is entirely filled with zeros except for entries lying on the diagonal in correspondence of the translational DOFs of the model, which are filled with the nodal mass.
As far as my knowledge goes, this corresponds to a lumped formulation of the mass matrix, which is also the form I am most used to see such matrix in.
Then, after a few passages, I found out it generated a new mass matrix for the model (defined on G-set, for those more accustomed to the tool) which is instead not diagonal anymore, but attributes some mass also to the connections between nodes (i.e., out-of-diagonal submatrices are non-zero).
I cannot understand how such a transformation could have been made, and the meaning of those contributions.
In particular, my main goal would be that of retrieving information about polar moment of inertia of the model for debugging purposes, so I would also need to understand how that could be retrieved from the mass matrix mentioned.
For the lumped mass case it is easy, one just needs to sum all entries of mass matrix relative to z-rotation DOFs, but in this case I am not so sure about what to do.

I don't think anyone will be able to help you if you don't state where you're getting this information from. "I've reached a passage [...] Then, after a few passages, I found..." does not allow anyone to follow along what you are describing.
